# Get Field BookMark

Tags: c#, com, ms-word

I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace in a console application to get form data from a MSWord document. In this MSWord doc are fields that have each been assigned a bookmark which I am using as an id.

I would like to be able to retrieve the value of a field its bookmark and store it in a dictionary.I am only able to get the value of each field but not the bookmark AND the field.

Is there a way that I could do something like wdField.Result.Bookmark to get a field's bookmark? I looked at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but am having a difficult time getting this right. Here is the foreach loop that I am enumerating with:

```
     foreach (Field wdField in oWordDoc.Fields)
           {
             wdField.Select(); 
             string fieldText = wdField.Result.Text
             Console.WriteLine(fieldText);   
             //string fieldBookMark = wdField.Result.BookMark
           }
```

Comment: bookmark belongs `Bookmarks collection`. To get the text of it you need to refer to `bookmarks(name).range.text`

Comment: This essentially answers my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KazJaw is right: if you have all the target text "bookmarked", you can rely just on `BookMarks`. Sample code:

```
foreach (Bookmark bookMark in oWordDoc.Bookmarks)
{
    string bmName = bookMark.Name;
    Range bmRange = bookMark.Range;
    string bmText = bmRange.Text;
}
```

Or:

```
Range bmRange = oWordDoc.Bookmarks["bookmark name"].Range;
```

Comment: Tested and works. I feel bad that I cannot give rep to KazJaw as well for his answer. But you both nevertheless solved my problem. I was not aware that I the bookmark object could contain text. Now I know.
Thank you, sirs.

Comment: @GoofBall No problem. I guess that KazJaw does not care too much (points are not everything in life :)). When you post a comment and don't write an answer afterwards (more than half an hour since his comment) is because you just want to share the idea but not come into the exact problem (his answer was generic, for VB/VBA rather than for C#). Some times it is enough: if you would have written your comment "... answers my question" before my answer, I wouldn't have written anything.

Comment: @GoofBall, it's fine, this time I was too lazy to make it as a full answer but Varocarbas was first to do so and he made it right and clear.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've spend an hour trying to get this answer.  Exactly what I needed.